# Re-install Python 2.6 on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: python, macos, build, compilation

Quite a while back I deleted the 2.6 directory that contained the built in Mac OS X Python install, and now I am in need of having it back. How might one go about re-compiling and installing Python to the original location?

Solutions like [Fink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fink), [brew](https://brew.sh/), and [MacPorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts) are all things I'm aware of, but if they are capable of solving my problem I don't know how to use them in that fashion. I need the install to be in the original location (`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions`) and to work as it originally did.

Comment: If you install the macports python, also install python_select. Then you can use the macports python as your default python. No need to reinstall the apple version.

Comment: The default python in OS X contains stuff like Objective-C bridge. A custom Python installation doesn't have those.

Comment: using python_select does not remedy my problem.  I know how to install any version of python and get it working as my default python, but I need to re-install the original osx python in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to reinstall OS X 10.6 over your existing installation.  As noted in the comments, it's not practical to build an exact duplicate of the Apple-supplied system Python because of the numerous Apple tweeks although many of them are published by Apple [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/) (you can drill down to a particular OS X release and find the open source components that went into it along with the Apple-supplied patches).  But the OS X installer makes it easy and generally foolproof to reinstall all of OS X without affecting files in your home directories or most documented customizations.  All bets are off if you've made other changes or deletions to files in `/System/Library` or `/usr` (other than `/usr/local`); as you've learned, don't do that!  As always, it is prudent to do a full backup of your hard drive before you begin.  A reinstall shouldn't take more than a couple of hours which will be a lot less time than trying to recreate the system Python from source.

Comment: From personal experience, this is the safest and easiest way to get Python working again.

Comment: Thats the conclusion I kind of came to on my own.  Thanks for validating :P

Comment: The simplest solution actually turned out to be installing Lion.  Lesson learned.  Don't use sudo to delete things unless you really really really know what you're doing.

Comment: If we have deleted things from our System/Library and /usr/local what is your recommendation?